# Converting 3d pie chart to 2d piechart while rotating using google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I can able to create a 3d pie chart using google charts,but while rotating it's converting to 2d pie chart even though i set the options is3D:true, can anyone please help me how to fix this issue.

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                ['Work', 11],
                ['Eat', 2],
                ['Commute', 2],
                ['Watch TV', 2],
                ['Sleep', 7]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'My Daily Activities',
                is3D: true,
                pieHole: 0.25,
                pieStartAngle: 0,
                animation:
                {
                    startup: true,
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'out'
                }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                if (options.pieStartAngle < 360) {
                    options.pieStartAngle++;
                    // options.is3D = true;
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        // options.is3D = true;
                        chart.draw(data, options);
                    }, 1);
                }
            });
            // options.is3D = true;
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily converting to 2d, I believe it is simply a bug with the 3d chart. if you draw the chart beginning at `pieStartAngle: 360` without rotating, it doesn't draw properly...

Comment: Thank you whiteHat, i have to rotate the 3d pie chart only. if we give pieStartAngle: 360 it's working fine for 2d. is there any fix for this issue.

Comment: not that I'm aware of, I believe this is something that would need to be fixed in the API, maybe enter a ticket with their support...

Comment: Thank you @WhiteHat, i need one more help, how can we add the border for pie chart. is't possiable?